# como eliminar un elemento de un array en angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">

    <h1>HOJA DE LISTA</h1>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="contact-item" ng-repeat="alumno in alumnos | orderBy:'nombre' | filter:buscador">
            <div class="nombre">{{alumno.nombre}} {{alumno.telefono}}</div>
            <span class="curso">-{{alumno.curso}}</span>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Cargar contacto</h2>
        <br> Nombre: <input type="text" ng-model="NuevoAlumno.nombre">
        <br> Telefono: <input type="text" ng-model="NuevoAlumno.telefono">
        <br> curso: <input type="text" ng-model="NuevoAlumno.curso">
        <br> buscador:
        <input type="text" name="buscador" ng-model="buscador">
        <br>

        <button ng-click="guardar()">guardar</button>
        <button ng-click="eliminar()">eliminar</button>
        <br>






    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

ACA EMPIEZA MI SCRIPT

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
```

app.controller("Controller", function($scope){

```
   $scope.alumnos=[];


$scope.guardar = function(){

    $scope.alumnos.push({nombre: $scope.NuevoAlumno.nombre, telefono: $scope.NuevoAlumno.telefono, curso: $scope.NuevoAlumno.curso});
    $scope.NuevoAlumno = null;
}

var elemento = $scope.buscador;
   if(elemento==$scope.buscador){
     $scope.eliminar = function(elemento){

    $scope.alumnos.splice(elemento,1);
    $scope.buscador = null;
   }
```

}

});

Comment: A ver si entendi. Cuando se presione eliminar, se eliminaran todos los registros de alumnos?

Comment: El codigo que posteaste necesita machone learning para entender lo qie realmente necesita hacer. Te recomiendo que po gas un codigo que sea sintacticame te correcro. Gracias

Comment: ¿Como sabes cual de todos quieres eliminar? ¿El botón eliminar, no debería repetirse por cada alumno? Esta línea `$scope.eliminar.splice[x,1];` debería lanzar un error de sintaxis.

Comment: ya corregi,,,marcos para saber cual de todos eliminar .....puse un filtro el boton del filtro se llama "buscador" ahi filtro por nombre los datos que hay que eliminar ,  el codigo se trata de un cuardernito en donde se carga listas de alumnos ....que tenia que buscar por nombre y tener la posibilidad de eliminar y añadir